# R code runs well on one computer but not on another (via Task Scheduler in RScript.exe)

Tags: r, rscript, windows-task-scheduler

My issue is: when I run the following code from one laptop in RScript.exe via Task Scheduler, I get the desired output; that is the email is sent. But when I run the same code on another machine in RScript.exe via Task Scheduler, it doesn't run. Another machine (machine 2) is able to send emails (when only the code for email is run), so I think the issue is with the following part.
**results <- get_everything(query  = q, page = 1, page_size = 2, language = "en", sort_by = "popularity", from = Yest, to = Today)**

I am unable to find what is the issue here. Can someone please help me with this?

My code is:

```
library(readxl)
library(float)
library(tibble)
library(string)
library(data.table)
library(gt)
library(tidyquant)
library(condformat)
library(xtable)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(newsanchor)
library(blastula)

Today <- Sys.Date()
Yest <- Sys.Date()-1

results <- get_everything(query  = "Inflation", page = 1, page_size = 2, language = 
          "en", sort_by = "popularity", from = Yest, to = Today, api_key = 
           Sys.getenv("NEWS_API_KEY"))
                      
OP <- results$results_df

OP <- OP[-c(1, 5:9)]
colnames(OP) <- c("News Title", "Description", "URL")

W <- print(xtable(OP), type="html", print.results=FALSE, align = "l")

email1 <-
  compose_email(
    body = md(
    c("<tr>", "<td>", "<table>", "<tr>", "<td>", "<b>", "Losers News", "</b>", W, 
      "</td>", "</tr>", "</table>","</td>", "<td>")    
     )
    )

 email1 %>%
 smtp_send(
 from = "abc@domain.com",
 to = "pqr@domain.com",
 subject = "Hello",
 credentials = creds_key(
  "XYZ"
 )
)
```

Comment: Did you check if the other machine has all the needed packages installed?

Comment: Well, the code runs well when run from RStudio and does not give any errors, even for any packages. I guess that means all required packages are already installed. If one of the packages was missing, I would have got an error even in RStudio correct?

Comment: Is NEWS_API_KEY set on the second machine?

Comment: Yes, NEWS_API_KEY is set on 2nd machine.

Comment: For short-term solution: run `Rscript ...` on second machine from CMD or PowerShell and review the console output to see specific errors. For long-term solution for other future errors: have PowerShell call `Rscript` and redirect output/errors to log. Review logs periodically.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help! I ran my script from PowerShell and found my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you schedule jobs, consider using a command line shell such as PowerShell or Bash to handle the automation steps, capture, and log errors and messages. Rscript fails on the second machine for some unknown reason which you cannot determine since you do not receive any error messages from console using TaskScheduler.

Therefore, consider PowerShell to run all needed `Rscript.exe` calls and other commands and capture all errors to date-stamped log file. Below script redirects all console output to a .log file with messages. When `Rscript` command fails, the log will dump error or any console output (i.e., `head`, `tail`) below it. Regularly check logs after scheduled jobs.

**PowerShell script** *(save as .ps1 file)*

```
cd "C:\path\to\scripts"

& {
    echo "`nAutomation Start: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

    echo "`nSTEP 1: myscript.R - $(Get-Date -format 'u')"
    Rscript myscript.R

    # ... ADD ANY OTHER COMMANDS ...
    

    echo "`nCAutomation End: $(Get-Date -format 'u')"

} 3>&1 2>&1 > "C:\path\to\logs\automation_run_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd').log"
```

**Command Line** *(to be used in Task Scheduler)*

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File myscheduler.ps1
```

Note: Either change directory in TaskScheduler job settings where `myscheduler.ps1` resides or run absolute path in `-File` argument.

Comment: Awesome! I could finally figure out what the error was! Thanks! The error was "You did not specify your API key as an argument or as a global variable. See documentation for further info. "  When I specify my API key in the code, the code works now. I already tried to set up the key with "Set_api_key" in my R environment, but it seems like it doesn't work and I have to specify the key in my code.  Is there any way to set up the key as a global variable and not in the code?

Comment: Yes, you can add user environment or if you have admin rights system environment variables. Simply type *environment variables* in Windows Start or search online to see how. Restart R session to read as `Sys.getenv`.

Comment: But again consider this longer term solution if using Task Scheduler to capture this and other potential future errors.

Comment: Yes, I scheduled my R script via PowerShell so that I can now capture all the logs. Thanks for your help!